# Converting triple list to a double list using flatMap

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

pojos look like this:

```
public class Obj {
    List<Entities> entities;    
}

public class Entities { 
    List<Fields> fields;    
}

public class Fields {
    List<Value> values; //Get only first member : values.get(0)!!!!
}


public class Value {    
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }       
}
```

Want to get `List<List<String>>` - (List of Entities containing the values)

This what I tired, but it returns just List

```
 obj.getEntities().stream()                     
            .map(m -> m.getFields())
            .flatMap(o -> o.stream())
            .map( k -> k.getValues().get(0).getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this is working, but doesn't look nice

```
List<List<String>> s1 = obj.getEntities().stream()                      
            .map(m -> m.getFields().stream()
                    .map(o -> o.getValues().get(0).getValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())                                           )                         
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it more readable by extracting the function into a variable:

```
    Function<Entities, List<String>> extractFirstFieldsValues =  m -> m.getFields().stream()
            .map(o -> o.getValues().get(0).getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<List<String>> s1 = obj.getEntities().stream()
            .map(extractFirstFieldsValues)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If desired you could do the same with `o -> o.getValues().get(0).getValue()` and instead of having one complex lambda you would have three simple ones.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell why you find that *not nice*, I could only think of this way, but it's hardly any nicer, may be a little bit more readable:

```
obj.getEntities().stream()
                 .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getFields().stream()
                      .map(f -> f.getValues().get(0).getValue())))
                 .collect(Collectors.mapping(
                       x -> x.collect(Collectors.toList()),
                       Collectors.toList()));
```